# Angular | Dynamically adding components in innerHTML

Tags: angular

Im developing a blog in Angular.

This is how the app works:

1. Angular fetches a blog post from a server:

   this.content = body.content;

   // content is : <h1>Some title for a blog post</h1><p>Content here...</p><p>More content..</p>
2. Angular injects the fetched HTML code into an element as innerHTML:

Above solution works perfectly for standard HTML tags.

**Question:** How can I implement a similar solution that supports custom components?

Example: If `content` contains a custom component, ie:

// content is : <h1>Some title for a blog post</h1><app-custom-component></app-custom-component>

''

Comment: I think it's not possible. `<app-custom-component></app-custom-component>` is an angular code. The angular code will be converted to vanilla js code while building and In production, you're running JavaScript code.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/